# Why do homeomorphisms tend to keep the shape?

Tags: general-topology

We say that $\alpha:U \to V$ is a homeomorphism if $\alpha$ carries $U$ onto $V$ in a one-to-one fashion and if both $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ are continuous. Now the word homeomorphism comes from *Greek* and it means "similar form"; which is the relation beetween our two conditions up here in the definition of a homeomorphism and its etymological meaning? I mean what would happen if we didn't specify that $\alpha^{-1}$ is continuous or $\alpha$ is bijective? Then $\alpha$ would keep the same form? I think the answer is negative, but why **these two** conditions suffice for $\alpha$ to preserve forms? Why don't we add a third condition, such as $D\alpha$ must be continuous? The same questions could fit well also for isomorphisms.

Answer (score 3):

Injectivity guarantees that no two points in $U$ are "welded" in $V$.
For example: if $U=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$, $V=[0,2]$ and $\alpha(t)=t$ if $t\in[0,1]$ and $\alpha(t)=t-1$ if $t\in[2,3]$.

Suprajectivity prevents that points or regions of $V$ can be ignored.

Continuity prevents $U$ from "tearing".

The continuity of the inverse is a bit more difficult to see. If the topology of $V$ is coarser than of $U$, a continuous, bijective application $\alpha$ can "glue" regions in $V$ that are torn appart in $U$, and the inverse won't be continuous.

This answer is intentionally in an informal style. I guess that this is what you expect, based on your question. If it si not the case, just tell.